# Lookup and cell referencing

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the lookup formula. This is the formula I use:

```
=LOOKUP(D4,Roster!C3:C184,Roster!D3:D184)
```

Naturally I would have to copy this down the column. The problem I am having is that when I copy it down the column, the references also change.

```
=LOOKUP(D5,Roster!C4:C185,Roster!D4:D185)<br />
=LOOKUP(D6,Roster!C5:C186,Roster!D5:D186)<br />
etc
```

What I want to happen though is to have the Dcolumn change without changing the reference for the Roster. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it: `=LOOKUP(D4,Roster!C$3:C$184,Roster!D$3:D$184)`

The `$` locks the cell reference.

Comment: For more information, see _The difference between absolute, relative and mixed references_ on the [Office Excel help page](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Overview-of-formulas-d258ec72-149a-42ac-8eae-b50a667eb491#bmusing_references_in_formulas).

Comment: You can also get the same result using this formula: `=LOOKUP(D4,Roster!C$3:D$184)`